How to correct the conversion of decimal numbers to simplified fractions using the Euclidean algorithm?
I am attempting to implement an algorithm to convert decimal numbers into simplified fractions in C. To achieve this, I am using the decimal_to_fraction function which utilizes the Euclidean algorithm to simplify fractions. However, I am encountering an issue where some conversions do not result in the expected fractions.
For example, when converting the decimal number 1.67, the output is 167/100, which is an improper fraction. The correct result should be 10/6, as 1.67 is equivalent to 10/6 as a fraction.
Here is the relevant snippet of code:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int gcd(int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0)
        return a;
    return gcd(b, a % b);
}

void decimal_to_fraction(double decimal, int *numerator, int *denominator) {
    const double EPSILON = 1.0e-7;
    double num = decimal;
    int d = 1;

    while (fabs(num - round(num)) > EPSILON) {
        num *= 10;
        d *= 10;
    }

    *numerator = round(num);
    *denominator = d;

    int divisor = gcd(*numerator, *denominator);
    *numerator /= divisor;
    *denominator /= divisor;
}

int main() {
    double numbers[] = {1.00, 1.67, 0.83, 0.50, 1.00, 1.50};
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers) / sizeof(numbers[0]); i++) {
        int numerator, denominator;
        decimal_to_fraction(numbers[i], &numerator, &denominator);
        printf("%.2f = %d/%d\n", numbers[i], numerator, denominator);
    }

    return 0;
}

How can I correct this issue to ensure that decimal numbers are correctly converted into simplified fractions using the Euclidean algorithm (or any other method)? I am open to suggestions or modifications to the code to achieve the desired result.

10/6 is not 1.67.  It's 1.66666666...  Hint:  167/100 is a lowest-terms fraction.  It cannot be simplified beyond that.

“The correct result should be 10/6, as 1.67 is equivalent to 10/6 as a fraction”: no it isn’t. The solution 167/100 is already correct. There is no problem here to solve.

@Exponecial Why? He already has a correct solution, and a correct technique. And why are you addressing that comment to me?

What you seem to want is different from what you're asking for, like:  Given a floating-point value, find the fraction with the smallest denominator that's within +/- 0.005 of that value.  The answer would involve computing the continued fraction and stopping when you get within tolerance: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction
